# How to calculate the value of string in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a store procedure in Mysql, in this I do some query to get a string @str = 5*2+1 then I want to calculate this string and return a number.
Like in sql server I can do `exec ('select'+ @str)` and it returns 11

Thanks

Comment: Exec in mysql is not support. I already try this

Comment: I mean just the `SELECT` part. It's not clear what your goal is here. Where is the `5*2+1` coming from?

Comment: I have a string @str = 5*2+1 so I want to calculate it then return a number

Comment: When you say `@str` you mean what? In a stored procedure?

Comment: yes in SP. I have a store procedure, in this I do some query to get a string @str = 5*2+1 then I want to calculate this string and return a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Screenshot of command from MySQL Workbench]

You can use the following, but be careful with SQL injection when using the dynamic queries:

```
prepare stmt1 from 'select 5*2+1';
execute stmt1;
deallocate prepare stmt1;
```

Using your code example, try this (be careful with SQL injection!)

```
set @Calc = concat('select ', '5*2+1', ' as result');
prepare stmt1 from @Calc;
execute stmt1;
deallocate prepare stmt1;
```

Comment: I've just try this querry but it throw out all the string, not the result: 
prepare calc from 'select ?';
execute calc using @Calc_;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE calc;
then it returns: ((1*2)/3)*100/1000

Comment: Here is my result: http://nw9.upanh.com/b5.s36.d1/1da0e69f7e13e2dced0d4e2023c585ab_54924689.123.png

Comment: Cannot load your screenshot. Can you show the exact code you use and how you passing that code to the MySQL?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/H8983.jpg

Comment: set @Calc_ = '5*2+1';
prepare calc from 'select ? as Results';
execute calc using @Calc_;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE calc;

Answer (score 1):

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'SELECT 5*2+1 as eval';
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/10741)
- [MySQL Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: Why such a heavy-handed approach instead of just calling `SELECT`?

Comment: @tadman because the OP is looking for alternative of `EXEC`. And also maybe because the OP is just simplifying an example.

Comment: Storing SQL in your database, even a portion of it, is an extraordinarily bad idea. MySQL does not have the injection protection provided in the client layer.

Comment: @tadman which of my answer says that it stores sql statement in the database?

Comment: If it wasn't in the database, you could simply send in the `SELECT` query directly. This seems like an attempt to avoid making a permanent stored procedure and instead making a generic facility to evaluate arbitrary SQL instead, something that always ends in tears.

Comment: I think we have different understanding on the OP. I was just answering the question directly -- the alternative of `EXEC()`. I do not really know what the OP's intention or whatsoever. Maybe you have and you can add it on your answer.

Comment: @JW do you have any solutions else? I just want to calculate the value of string by anyway

Comment: @VN_Khoai how concatenating your string? `PREPARE stmt1 FROM CONCA('SELECT ', yourStringExpression,' as eval');`

Comment: @JW still the same. Here is my result: http://nw9.upanh.com/b5.s36.d1/1da0e69f7e13e2dced0d4e2023c585ab_54924689.123.png

Comment: i can't see the image

Answer (score 0):

Yes, technically you can do this, but it is a dangerous form of [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/), so it's probably a very bad idea.

There's a reason people do not use `eval` or anything like it to do simple math.